# Is it possible to create equations within mongodb documents?

Tags: html, json, node.js, mongodb, robo3t

I currently have a mongodb document that is being displayed as a react component. It is possible to compete math within this document at output the result? See example below:

document:

```
{ 
  "label" : variable
  "equation" : 3 * 5
}
```

HTML:

variable
15

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: To start I just want to be able to compute a number in the database. eventyually, I would like to use to variables entered in by the user of the website to compute a third variable. please see below: EDIT: 
{
    "label" : "var1",
    "type" : "text"
 }, 
{
    "label" : "var2",
    "type" : "text"
}, 
 {
    "label" : "var 3",
    "type" : "var1 + var2"
}

Comment: It depends on your needs, but you could simply store the equation as a string and evaluate it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No; there is a short list of [data types in MongoDB/BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/), and none of them are suitable for storing a mathematical formula.

If your users of the website have entered numbers 3 and 5, you might as well just do the calculation in your app and store the result 15 as an ordinary number.